# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/autobot/nohup.out'

Tags: python, django, apache2

I used virtual env to host my python project on to the local host but 
when visit my localhost, the website is IOError at /gobot/dcae3db9ad68d046e97d503da41a068aed8663feec28882d94
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/autobot/nohup.out'

Why am I getting this error ? Please help.

Internal Server Error:

```
/gobot/dcae3db9ad68d046e97d503da41a068aed8663feec28882d94
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/gobot/views.py", line 360, in dispatch
    return generic.View.dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/myproject/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/autobot/gobot/views.py", line 352, in get
```

Comment: How are you running the program ? Is you the `user` you are running with have `write` permission to `/home/ubuntu/autobot/` ?

Comment: ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 - running the program
and after running the program :-
September 12, 2019 - 06:01:21
Django version 1.10.7, using settings 'exp.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /gobot/dcae3db9ad68d046e97d503da41a068aed8663feec28882d94
Then I get those errors.